# System calls in Groovy fails

Tags: java, shell, groovy, processbuilder

I am exploring Groovy on Windows 10 and when I use

```
"java -version".execute().text
```

I get no output and upon inspecting the error output using:

```
def pb = new ProcessBuilder("java -version").redirectErrorStream(true);
def result = pb.start()
println result.text
```

it goes:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -version": CreateProcess error=2, Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -version": CreateProcess error=2, Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet
at java_lang_ProcessBuilder$start$0.call(Unknown Source)
at test$_run_closure2.doCall(test.groovy:59)
at test.run(test.groovy:51)
```

It seems that Groovy completely disregards the PATH and only searches in the current directory. For instance, if I create a batch file inside the same directory, Groovy will run it. However, if I try to pass it any arguments it fails. It appears that Groovy interprets the arguments as part of the filename.

It feels like Groovy is either obscenely inept or I am approaching this problem the wrong way...

I'm used to doing `system("java -version")` in Ruby, so what the idiomatic way to do this in Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> "java -version".execute().text
> ```

Does not give you any output, because this commands writes it output to stdout.  (e.g. `java -version 2>/dev/null` prints nothing)

> ```
> def pb = new ProcessBuilder("java -version").redirectErrorStream(true)
> ```

Would work, but the error there is actually, that you try to run the program `java -version`, which does not exist.  So one way to go here is:

```
def pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-version").redirectErrorStream(true)
```